# Associate office documents with XP Mode with Vmware

Tags: windows, vmware

is it possibleto associate a file extention of MS Office with XP Mode with Vmware. I have successfully created shortcuts to run XP mode office application, however I am not sure as to how to link the application with a file extension.

Comment: great question; added to favotrites

Comment: Are you talking about XP mode as in the feature in Windows 7 Pro / Ultimate? Because that is not Vmware, that is Microsoft Virtual PC. If you clarify that, you might get an answer.